# login form, createTicket and UnicodeDecodeError bug and potential solution

Tags: plone

I recently migrated a Plone site from Plone 4.1.4 to Plone 4.2.4.  The migration itself reported no errors.  However, in the last couple of days we have received reports of very strange behavior.  Certain users could not log in and received a UnicodeDecodeError in plone.session.tktauth and the createTicket function (see below) and were sent back to the login form.  None of these users had utf-8 characters in their username or password, which was the strangest part about all of this.

Upon some investigation, I saw that plone.session was version 3.5.2 and two lines had the encoding  set to None.  In my previous version 3.5, the encoding in createTicket and splitTicket was set to utf-8.  By changing these lines to utf-8 I resolved the error (so far!):

```
def createTicket(secret, userid, tokens=(), user_data='', ip='0.0.0.0', timestamp=None, encoding='utf8', mod_auth_tkt=False):
...

def splitTicket(ticket, encoding='utf8'):
...
```

Not sure if anyone else has experienced this or if this is a bug, but I thought I would put it out there.  Hope this helps anyone suffering from the same problem.

Best,
Patrick

Original Error:

```
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 28, in _call
Module Products.CMFFormController.ControllerBase, line 231, in getNext
Module Products.CMFFormController.Actions.TraverseTo, line 38, in __call__
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 105, in __call__
Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 127, in __call__
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
Module script, line 29, in logged_in
<FSControllerPythonScript at /Plone/logged_in>
Line 29
Module Products.PlonePAS.tools.membership, line 624, in loginUser
Module Products.PlonePAS.plugins.cookie_handler, line 93, in login
Module Products.PluggableAuthService.PluggableAuthService, line 1140, in updateCredentials
Module plone.session.plugins.session, line 220, in updateCredentials
Module plone.session.plugins.session, line 140, in _setupSession
Module plone.session.tktauth, line 177, in createTicket

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: This is not so much a question as a bug report. Please keep those to the Plone issue tracker. SO is really for Q&A only.

Comment: Noted.  I wasn't sure if it was a bug or not and I figured SO would be a good place for public documentation.  I will refer to the Issue Tracker if I come across a bug again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a discussion about this here: https://github.com/plone/plone.session/commit/0d4079c0e0ceff780ab10ce3206e99c59c4010a2#L1L200

Comment: Ah!  I didn't see that in my google searches.  Glad to know I wasn't the only one looking into it.  I'll check if a newer version of the package gets installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solution, where encoding=None in plone.session.tktauth, set to utf8:

```
def createTicket(secret, userid, tokens=(), user_data='', ip='0.0.0.0', timestamp=None, encoding='utf8', mod_auth_tkt=False):
...

def splitTicket(ticket, encoding='utf8'):
```